# jQuery edit in place - update/pre-fill field every time the content has been edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events, jeditable

I am using the jQuery [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) (amazing script btw) to create an edit-in-place form. So, on top of the form, I load the script. Then, the form consists of several hidden fields, which pre-populate themselves with the text from the relevant < p> tags.

With the help of you all here, this is an example of how the field is pre populated:

Text from edit-in-place page:

```
<p class="autogrow" style="width: 300px" id="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
```

Javascript script which does the business:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
  $("#input_3_2").val($("#title").text());
});
</script>
```

The problem that I have, is that at the moment, field with ID 'input_3_2' is pre-populated with the text from paragraph with ID 'title' when the page loads.

Is it possible to re-fill/ or re-populate the field every time the paragraph is changed?

Comment: Is your div with `contenteditable="true"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the callback

```
$("#title").editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
    type     : 'textarea',
    submit   : 'OK',
    callback : function(value, settings) {
        $("#input_3_2").val( value );     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the `DOM` for each text field and it's relevant `p` tags. So I say, traversing depends upon the `HTML` structure you use. Here I think you can do- place your text fields just before to it's relevant  `p` tags. And you can traverse  `DOM` with something like -

```
   $("input:text").each(function(){
           $(this).val($(this).next('p').text());
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, i cannot move the text fields. Reason being, i am using a wordpress plugin for the form, and the Jeditable content is loaded in a HTML block before the form fields. The plugin cannot submit anything posted in the html block, which is why i need to copy the content to form fields which are later saved in the database.

Comment: Alternatively, could we get the script function to run on pressing the submit button? The problem here is that i cannot edit the submit button itself, so, again, it will need to be a code which targets the click of the submit button.

Comment: Well, to select set of elements they must have some sort of mechanisms added to it like classes,ids or even their position. In your case as you are using wordpress, it also adds some classes or id automatically. You can use them or look out some element either before or after your Jeditable content and apply traversing. If you can show the source, it will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by editing submit button? You are using wordpress, you can edit anything if you know the where to look and what it mean !

Answer (score 0):

If the `p` has the attribute `contenteditable="true"` you can subscribe to it's keyup event.

For example if this is your html

```
<p id="TargetP" contenteditable="true">
    Some text
</p>
<input type="hidden" id="TargetHidden"/>

<!-- This anchor is just for the purpose of the demonstration -->
<a href="javascript:;" id="ShowContent">Show hidden's value</a>
```

​this script will do the work

```
$(function() {
    // declare the function that will take value from p 
    // and put it into the hidden
    function updateHidden() {
        $("#TargetHidden").val($("#TargetP").text());
    }

    // Call it for the first time to update the hidden
    updateHidden();

    // assign it each time the key is released when the p is being
    // edited
    $("#TargetP").keyup(updateHidden);

    // just a dummy action to show the content of the hidden at the
    // given time
    $("#ShowContent").click(function() {
        alert($("#TargetHidden").val());
    });
});​
```

[Here is the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Isis/BupuD/3/).

---

However I'd rather prefer the `onsubmit` event of the `form` if it is synchronous of course.

```
<!-- onsubmit="return false" is placed to prevent the form from being
     submitted remove it in production. -->
<form id="TargetForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <p id="TargetP" contenteditable="true">
        Some text
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" id="TargetHidden"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit me" />

    <!-- Demo's helper link -->
    <a href="javascript:;" id="ShowContent">Show content</a>
</form>​
```

And the script

```
// declare the function that will take value from p 
// and put it into the hidden
function updateHidden() {
    $("#TargetHidden").val($("#TargetP").text());
}

$(function() {
    // Call it for the first time to update the hidden
    updateHidden();

    // subscribe to the submit event of your form
    $("#TargetForm").submit(function() {
        updateHidden();
    });

    // dummy function for demo purposes
    $("#ShowContent").click(function() {
        alert($("#TargetHidden").val());
    });
});​
```

[And working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Isis/BupuD/5/)

**P.S.** If you have any other conditions. Comment out and I'll make updates.